# How to do COUNT with CASE and ELSE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have the following `SELECT`:

```
SELECT column,
COUNT(CASE WHEN column='x' THEN 1 END) AS count_x,
COUNT(CASE WHEN column='y' THEN 1 END) AS count_y,
COUNT(CASE WHEN column='a' THEN 1 END) AS count_a,
COUNT(CASE WHEN column='b' THEN 1 END) AS count_b
...
```

I want to modify it so that it will keep counting `x` and `y` but any other case that's not `x` or `y` count as `count_other`

How can I do that? Where do I put the `ELSE` in this case?

Sample data:

| id | column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | x |
| 3 | y |
| 4 | a |
| 5 | b |
| 6 | b |
| 7 | c |

Expected result:

| count_x | count_y | count_other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input tables and expected output?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, you already have x,y,a,b do you want `count(case when column not in ('x','y','a','b') then 1 end)`

Comment: @lemon right away. Stu I want to only leave x,y and all others count as one

Comment: Your question is confusing since you are showing us your attempt with columns you don't actually want so why include them at all? You have your answer though.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I left the columns I don't want because I wrote that I want to modify the current query to count them as one. Next time I will try to be less specific and focus on the problem itself. Should I edit the post now as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following logic:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col = 'x' THEN 1 END) AS x,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col = 'y' THEN 1 END) AS y,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col = 'a' THEN 1 END) AS a,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col = 'b' THEN 1 END) AS b,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col NOT IN ('x', 'y') THEN 1 END) AS count_other
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I needed (Except I will also remove the CASES with `a` and `b`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select X count_x,Y count_y,count_other 
From(Select Case when Col not in ('X','Y') Then 'count_other' else col End Col From #TableNmae)T pivot (Count (Col) For col in (X,Y,count_other)) pvt;

Select col,Count() from #TableNmae Where col in ('X','Y') Group by col Union Select 'Othercolumns' col,Count() from #TableNmae Where col not in ('X','Y');

Select col ,Count(*) From(Select Case when col not in ('X','Y') then 'Othercolumns' else col end col from #TableNmae )T Group by col;

Select (Select COUNT() From #TableNmae Where col ='X') count_x, (Select COUNT() From #TableNmae Where col ='Y') count_y, (Select COUNT(*) From #TableNmae Where col not in ('X','Y')) count_other;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).